# Typescript path in VS code

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, angular-cli

I can't get typescript paths to work for VS Code in an Angular cli project.

If you look at https://github.com/gatimus/multiple-test/blob/master/src/app1/app/app.module.ts#L3 throws

> [ts] Cannot find module 'shared/shared.module',

even though path is set in `tsconfig.app.json` and `settings.json` has the line

```
"typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib/"
```

Update: 
It seems the apps run but VS Code can't find the module. I have version 1.16.1
[image]

Comment: I did `git clone`,  `yarn`, `ng serve`. Have no problems running the app. Try to restart your `ng serve`.

Comment: @Kuncevic it seems that app runs but it is vscode that can't find the module, see updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renaming `tsconfig.app.json` to `tsconfig.json` and updating `.angular-cli.json` seems to work.

I am curious though, if the tsconfig file wasn't configurable in angular cli, how would you tell VS Code to use `tsconfig.app.json`?

Comment: it is good that you figure that out, you can now mark that as an answer ;)

Comment: It won't let me for 5 hours

Comment: You are a life saver! Thank you!

Comment: @WilliamLohan Apparently it doesn't work for tests :-(

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still struggling with this, I was having this problem in Atom and it was fixed by following the sym link. (cmnd/ctrl click on the module name that throws the error). This seems to suggest that it is an issue with the IDE and not angular.